# Queueing theory analysis

Tags: statistics, reference-request, queueing-theory

I'm looking for references that analyze $M/M/c/K/\infty/D$ queues as $K$ and $D$ vary and $K$ is finite. My motivation is to compare the availability and statistics of the service times between different queueing disciplines in systems that model web services under heavy load.